# Extbase Database-query with COUNT and GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, repository, typo3, extbase, typo3-6.1.x

I'm trying to make a DBquery in my Repository. I've already got one working, but what i wanted to was adapting it to use contraints instead of using setReturnRawQueryResult(TRUE). So i want to find all different types of $values in the table and count, how much of them exist. That's my code:

```
public function findAllDistinct($value, $category) {

    $query = $this->createQuery();

    $query->getQuerySettings()->setReturnRawQueryResult(TRUE);

    return $query
      ->statement('SELECT ' . $value . ', COUNT(*) AS \'num\' '
                . 'FROM tx_myextension_domain_model_job '
                . 'WHERE job_category =' . $category . ' '
                . 'GROUP BY ' .$value.'')
      ->execute();
}
```

And by the way, how to realize a "SELECT DISTINCT"?

Comment: You query will return distinct result.

Comment: I mean you already have `all different types of $values in the table and count, how much of them exist`  query.

Comment: yeah i know, but i don't wanna use the raw sql-statement but the provided methods from the extbase-framework...

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your question.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to provide a new Model and Repository, where you can write your query. E.g. if your new Model contains a property `num` that will get mapped.

I'm not sure about the need of the `TCA` for this case. But make sure you provide `uid` as a property and that it's unique.

Model:

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\ExtKey\Domain\Model;


/**
 * @author Daniel Siepmann <d.siepmann@web-vision.de>
 */
class FilterOption extends \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\DomainObject\AbstractEntity
{
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $title;

    /**
     * @var float
     */
    protected $value;

    /**
     * @var float
     */
    protected $min;

    /**
     * @var float
     */
    protected $max;

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getTitle()
    {
        return $this->title;
    }

    /**
     * @return float
     */
    public function getValue()
    {
        return $this->value;
    }

    /**
     * @return float
     */
    public function getMin()
    {
        return $this->min;
    }

    /**
     * @return float
     */
    public function getMax()
    {
        return $this->max;
    }
}
```

Repository:

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\ExtKey\Domain\Repository;


/**
 *
 * @author Daniel Siepmann <d.siepmann@web-vision.de>
 */
class FilterOptionRepository extends \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\Repository
{
    /**
     * Will find all options to filter for for a specific property.
     *
     * @param string $property The name of the property.
     *
     * @return NULL|[]
     */
    public function findFilterOptionForProperty($property)
    {
        if (in_array($property, [ 'house_types' ])) {
            return $this->findMmOptions($property);
        }
        return $this->findNumericOptions($property);
    }

    /**
     * Will find all options to filter for for a specific property.
     *
     * @param string $property The name of the property.
     *
     * @return NULL|[]
     */
    protected function findNumericOptions($property)
    {
        return $this->createQuery()
            ->statement($this->getNumericStatement($property))
            ->execute();
    }

    /**
     * Get SQL statement to fetch filter options from persistence,
     * for the given property if it's values are numeric.
     *
     * @param string $property The property to fetch.
     *
     * @return string The statement
     */
    protected function getNumericStatement($property)
    {
        // We have to fake UID, otherwise extbase will reuse previous
        // objects with same uid.
        $uidBase = rand(ord($property), getrandmax());

        // Return statement for single column.
        return '
            SELECT "' . $property . '" AS title, ' . $property . ' AS value,
                (SELECT min(' . $property . ') FROM tx_realty_objects WHERE ' . $this->getAdditionalWhereClause() . ') AS min,
                (SELECT max(' . $property . ') FROM tx_realty_objects WHERE ' . $this->getAdditionalWhereClause() . ') AS max,
                @rownum := @rownum + ' . $uidBase . ' AS uid
            FROM tx_realty_objects,
            (SELECT @rownum:=' . $uidBase . ') x
            WHERE ' . $this->getAdditionalWhereClause() . '
            GROUP BY ' . $property . '
            ORDER BY value;
        ';
    }
}
```